# Allow Execution, Deny Interactive login by GPO

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2008-r2, configuration, group-policy

Problem:

Accounts to log into work stations are locked down tightly and unable to run nessesary applications on windows 7 stations. Saving an admin accounts credentials to elevate access is currently used, however due to security policies the password must be rotated frequently and then changed on every system. The only way they will write off on exempting an admin user from the password rotation security is if it is denied Interactive and terminal login via GPO from the domain controller (windows 2008 r2 server)

Issure:

Denying the interactive login breaks its ability to authorize the elevated privileges required to run the software. Is there a policy setting that would override the fact the interactive login denial breaks this and allow it to authorize the elevated run on the limited operators account, or possibly a alternative option to make the admin account unusable to the security policys satisfaction?